# double progress bar prestashop installation

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to install Prestashop 1.7 on a server with Ubuntu 16.04 Apache, Mysql, Php 7.0.

I start the installation but after a second i get a generic error "an error has occurred" and i can see under the progress bar, it appears a new prestashop image with another progress bar. On Apache errors log there's nothing. Any ideas what can be wrong? I checked folder's ownership and permissions are ok.

you can see it on http://155.94.210.181/nautazon/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the zip archive that wasn't uploaded properly on the server. I didn't notice there had been an error on the ftp and the file was incomplete